# PHP/HTML: Replace everything between <TD colspan=6 ...> .... </TD>

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to replace everything between a TD-Tag that has the attribute/value colspan=6.

All this I want to replace ...

```
<TD colspan=6 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
  <TABLE>
    <TR>
      <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
    Some Text
    </font> 
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
    Some Text
    </font> 
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
    Some Text
    </font> 
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

...with this lines:

```
<TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
  <TABLE>
    <TR>
      <TD>frei</TD>
      Some Text
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

Any Ideas? Maybe with simple_html_dom.php?

Comment: If the HTML is generated by PHP, please include the code. If not, it can't be done with PHP (which is a server side language), but you should use something like Javascript (which is very good at DOM manipulation)

Comment: Use jquery dom traversing methods for this. As this is a kind of dom traverse and replace type thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with PHP and Regex:

```
$plan1 = preg_replace('~<TD colspan=6.*?</TR></TABLE></TD>~s", 
"<TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
<TABLE><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE></TD>', $plan1);
```

Comment: That is the obvious solution, but I'd check `http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp` for ex.